# pyinstaller - how to get the name of the random-generated temp folder?

Tags: pyinstaller

Is there a way to import the name (or the path) of the random-generated temp folder?

I know about `--runtime-tmpdir` which only defines the base path, but a random-named folder will still be created in that temp dir.

I see two (hacky) workarounds:

1. scan the temp folder and look for a folder that starts with "_MEI"
2. have a (uncompiled) script in the package that can be called from main.py and tell its location

But, whats the proper way of doing this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Found a better way: `getattr(sys, '_MEIPASS', 'NotRunningInPyInstaller')`

Old:

Found a way !
The temporary path is added automatically to `sys.path` by pyinstaller. So it can easily be extracted from there.